# Why is my system.poperties property unused?

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku, push

So I am trying to push to Heroku, but I got the following error:

```
Could not target platform: 'Java SE 15' using tool chain: 'JDK 11 (11)'.
```

Eventually, I found a post on StackOverflow that suggests adding a system.properties file into my project. I did that, but it still was not pushing. I looked into the system.properties file and saw that this property was unused and figured this would be my problem.
As you can see in the screenshot below it is unused and in my project directory, u can see at the bottom where I stored the system.properties file.

[image]

Now I do not really know what to do next, since I can't really find what to do next?

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's in the build.gradle? Is there any mention of 15 in there?

Comment: @roby Thanks for your help, I posted the answer below!

Answer (score 1):

With the help of roby I saw that my build.gradle file had the following line of code in it:

```
sourceCompatibility = '15'
```

When I removed this, it worked!!